# How to recursively write any large amount as a sum of 5 and 7 coins?

Tags: python

I am taking a discrete mathematics course and I do not figure it out how to make a recursive function in Python which transform any large amount in a sum of 5- and 7- coins.

I tried it for with 3- and 5- coins and it is working, but for 5- and 7- it does not and I did not find something about it like a rule or something.

```
    def change(amount) :
      assert( amount>= 12 )
      if amount==12 :
       return [5,7]
      if amount==14 :
       return [7,7]
      if amount==15:
       return [5,5,5]
      coins=change(amount-7)
      coins.append(7)
      return coins
```

I expect the output of the coins used, but it just does not work, it says "RunTime Error" when i send it.

Comment: Why do you expect that for any `amount`, `amount - 7` will ever reach 12, 14 or 15? If input is `45` then you get an infinite recursion

Comment: You might need a different approach. For example, for 100 it's not working because it repeatedly subtracts 7 and it ends up with 2, which isn't 12, 14 or 15. But it would work with 20 coins of 5.

Comment: How do you write 13 with only 5 and 7?

Comment: You cannot make any sum using 5 and  7.

Comment: For those asking about the "any sum" part, question states "any large amount".

Comment: @Tyberius 1787 is 7*1 + 356*5 so there is a solution. Or do I not understand the question?

Comment: @RomainReboulleau that was my mistake. My little code example only got the cases that had up to N total coins. I guess it would still be clearer if the OP defined what value was sufficiently large. Its not possible for 23 for example.

Comment: @Tyberius indeed, it appears that it works for integers greater than 23, and a few others under 23.

Comment: @RomainReboulleau yeah after thinking about it more, it does look like anything greater than 23 should work because after after this point you can generate any digit in the ones position and then just add ten repeatedly to it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the python code here, but the algorithm. As stated in the comments, always removing 7 first can lead you in cases with infinite recursion.

If the "amount" is large enough (I guess higher than 35 works, but you might want to do the math to find the exact limit), you can proceed like this:

```
def change(amount):
    if (amount % 5 == 0):
        return [5] * int(amount/5)
    elif (amount % 7 == 0):
        return [7] * int(amount/7)
    else:
        coins = change(amount-5)
        return coins.append(5)
```

This works for large enough values because after max 7 times removing 5, you will always get a result which is a multiple of 7.

There should be more clever ways to do this but it should work.

---

Knowing that the minimum value of 23, another approach (non recursive) would be to look at the modulo 5 division (`amount % 5`), and give 5 different solutions.

If it's 0, `amount` can be divided by 5, so it's just a list of 5s; if it's 1, remove 3*7 = 21, and what remains is a list of 5s; and so on. The following code gives you a correct answer for all `amount` greater than 23. You then just have to deal with the remaining cases, if necessary.

```
def change(amount):
    d = amount % 5
    if d == 0:
        return [5] * int(amount/5)
    elif d == 1:
        return [7] * 3 + [5] * int((amount-21)/5)
    elif d == 2:
        return [7] + [5] * int((amount-7)/5)
    elif d == 3:
        return [7] * 4 + [5] * int((amount-28)/5)
    elif d == 4:
        return [7] * 2 + [5] * int((amount-14)/5)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but first of all it should be written as a sum of 5s and 7s so those ifs should be changed. Moreover, i really do not figure it out how to set a limit. The biggest number which can not be written as a sum of 5s and 7s is 23, but there are smaller number, they should be taken as particular cases?

Comment: `[5] * n` is `[5, 5, .... , 5]` n times so it does give you what you need. The algorithm I propose should work for 24, 25, 26, 27 and 28, and since it works for those 5 consecutive values, it works for any greater value. So it's OK starting with 24.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a non recursive solution. It should actually work for any value for which there is a solution. Adding a `ValueError` exception somewhere should handle the cases where there is no solution. I'll try this later if I have time.

Comment: Thank you,I finally made it!

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun it might help you to look at a change making program that is actually recursive.

```
# amount paid and cost due in dollars.
def process(paid,cost):
    amount = int((float(paid)-float(cost))*100)
    names = ['penny','nickle','dime','quarter','halfdollar','dollar','2Piece','5Spot','Tenner','Dub','Fifty','CNote']
    made = {k:0 for k in names}
    return(makeChange(amount,made))

def makeChange(amount,made):
    # coin and bill values in cents 
    coins = [1,5,10,25,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000]
    coins.reverse()
    names = ['penny','nickle','dime','quarter','halfdollar','dollar','2Piece','5Spot','Tenner','Dub','Fifty','CNote']
    names.reverse()
    decode = {coins[n]:names[n] for n,k in enumerate(coins)}
    i = 0
    if(amount>0):
        while(coins[i]>amount):
            i+=1
        amount-=coins[i]
        made[decode[coins[i]]]+=1
    else:
        return(made)
    return(makeChange(amount,made))

test = process(20,11.73)
for k in test:
    if(test[k]!=0):
        print(k+":"+str(test[k]))
```

Comment: It inspired me, it was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 can all be represented by 5 and 7, we can create an algorithm that reduces the amount by 5 during each recursive call. Finally the recursion will achieve one of the base conditions listed in the if else statements. The code is shown below

```
def change(amount):
  if amount == 24:
    return [5, 5, 7, 7]
  if amount == 25:
    return [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
  if amount == 26:
    return [7, 7, 7, 5]
  if amount == 27:
    return [5, 5, 5, 5, 7]
  if amount == 28:
    return [7, 7, 7, 7]
  coins = change(amount-5)
  coins.append(5)
  return coins
```